# java.lang.ClassCastException happened when i run the java code which is about Java collections interface

Tags: java, exception, collections, jquery-ui-sortable

When i compile the java code,it can not be compiled correctly .but when i run the program,
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:java.lang.StringBuffer cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable.**

so i have two question :

1. Should the element which is added to the **SortedSet** or **SortedMap** must be **sortable?** Does this rule also works in any other interfaces in the java collections framwork
2. why did the program can be compiled correctly .but can not run ? what happened while the program is runing

   import java.util.*;

   ```
   public class SortMe {
       public static void main(String args[]) {
           SortedSet<StringBuffer> s = new TreeSet<StringBuffer>();
           s.add(new StringBuffer("Red"));
           s.add(new StringBuffer("White"));
           s.add(new StringBuffer("Blue"));
           System.out.println(s.first());
       }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 3):

`SortedSet` only take `Comparable` types in their generic declaration, as they use it to sort the elements inserted. Now since `StringBuffer` don't implement `Comparable`, so you get that exception.

```
SortedSet<T> --> `T` must implement `Comparable`
```

From the [`documentation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html): -

> All elements inserted into a sorted set must implement the Comparable
>   interface (or be accepted by the specified comparator). Furthermore,
>   all such elements must be mutually comparable: e1.compareTo(e2) (or
>   comparator.compare(e1, e2)) must not throw a ClassCastException for
>   any elements e1 and e2 in the sorted set. Attempts to violate this
>   restriction will cause the offending method or constructor invocation
>   to throw a ClassCastException.

But the question is, why are you making `SortedSet<StringBuffer>` instead of `SortedSet<String>`?